# Should Philippians 2:11b read "to the glory of God" or "[is] in the glory of God"?

Tags: greek, philippians, grammatical-historical

The Vulgate version of Philippians 2:11 reads:

> **VUL** et omnis lingua confiteátur, quia Dóminus Jesus Christus **in glória est** De**i** Patr**is**.
>
> **Translation** and every tongue confess that the Lord Jesus Christ **is in the glory of** God the Father.

Which engenders the following reading of the Greek:

> **NA28** καὶ πᾶσα γλῶσσα ἐξομολογήσηται ὅτι κύριος Ἰησοῦς Χριστὸς **εἰς** δόξαν θεοῦ πατρός.
>
> **My Translation** and every tongue confess that [the] Lord Jesus Christ **[is] in** the glory of God the Father.

Whereas the prevailing understanding is:

> **My Translation** and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ **is Lord: to** the glory of God the Father.

### Question

Which one is more likely the intended meaning, or is there even possibly intended ambiguity/multivalence?

Comment: Wouldn't Paul have used ἐν instead of εἰς if he meant "in"?

Comment: One would think.

Comment: The literal rendering of the words καὶ πᾶσα γλῶσσα ἐξομολογήσηται ὅτι κύριος Ἰησοῦς Χριστὸς εἰς δόξαν θεοῦ πατρός is 'and every tongue confess that Lord Jesus Christ unto glory of God - Father. (One of the common translations of εἰς is 'unto'. The concept is '[motion into](http://biblehub.com/greek/1519.htm)'.

Comment: @NigelJ  But the Vultage has "is in", I think and that seems to be what we're comparing.

Comment: The OP states 'the intended meaning' and that is the intended meaning of the original text which is in Greek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly stated in the comments, in Classical Greek the preposition ἐν with the dative means “in”, while εἰς with the accusative means “into, towards”. However, in post-classical Greek the latter is increasingly used to mean “in”, for example in the Septuagint of  Numbers 35,33: καὶ οὐ μὴ φονοκτονήσητε τὴν γῆν εἰς ἣν ὑμεῖς κατοικεῖτε “do not pollute the land **in which** you live” (Vulgate: ne polluatis terram habitationis vestræ). The Vulgate obviously understood εἰς in the same way in Philippians 2,11.

The semantic shift from “into” to “in”, which begins in the Hellenistic period, is completed in Modern Greek, where the ordinary word for “in” is σ(ε), the continuation of Classical εἰς.

Comment: The answer lacks a primary source, though, which makes it not very authoritative.

Comment: @Ruminator. Is the LXX not a primary source?

Comment: It is a primary source for LXX studies but is not authoritative as to all koine usages. In other words, how can you disqualify the usage of EV simply by showing in the LXX it was used differently? Can you prove how the word "race" is used and not used in English by 3 examples from Sports Illustrated?

Answer (score 0):

**How do translations render the verse?**

**First group.**

Philippians 2:11  (NRSV)

> 11 And every tongue should confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the
>   glory of God the Father.

Philippians 2:11 (NIV)

> 11 and every tongue acknowledge that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the
>   glory of God the Father.

Philippians 2:11 (NASB)

> 11 and that every tongue will confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to
>   the glory of God the Father.

**Second group.**

Philippians 2:11 (DRA)

> 11 And that every tongue should confess that, the Lord Jesus Christ is
>   in the glory of God the Father.

Philippians 2:11 (NLV)

> 11 And every tongue will say Jesus Christ is Lord. Everyone will give
>   honor to God the Father.

Philippians 2:11  (JUB)

> 11 And that every tongue should confess that, the Lord Jesus Christ is
>   Lord in the glory of God the Father.

Ours translations fall into two discernible groups; the first separates Jesus Christ, show that he is distinct from the father, and is subject to him, whereas the second group does not.

When faced with such ambiguous passages and before making a decision, we look to the scriptures for similar passages, and the context of the verse in order to make a comparison.

**Paul, the writer of Philippians, gives the closest parallel to us, in Romans 10:9, which reads:**

Romans 10:9(NRSV)

> 9 Because[a] if you confess with your lips that Jesus is Lord and
>   believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be
>   saved.

Romans 10:9 (NABRE)

> 9 For, if you confess[a] with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and
>   believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be
>   saved.

Other verse which show the distinction between “God” and “Jesus”.

Titus 2:13  (NABRE)

> 13 As we await the blessed hope, the appearance[a] of the glory of the
>   great God and of our savior Jesus Christ,

Titus 2:13 King James Version (KJV)

> 13 Looking for that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the
>   great God and our Savior Jesus Christ;

Titus 1:4 (NABRE)

> 4 To Titus, my true child in our common faith: grace and peace from
>   God the Father and Christ Jesus our savior.

Titus 1:4 (KJV)

> 4 To Titus, mine own son after the common faith: Grace, mercy, and
>   peace, from God the Father and the Lord Jesus Christ our Savior.

**CONCLUSION.**

The prevailing is the correct translation

**My Translation** “and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ **is Lord: to** the glory of God the Father.”

We observe that My Translation maintains the distinction between “God the Father” and “Jesus is Lord”.
In context, we read that Jesus was exalted to a name above all others, by God the Father and that all creation in heaven and on earth bow to it. The highly exalted Jesus is called; “Lord” he is not called “God” or “Father”, but Paul says this is done; to the glory of the God the Father.

**Ambiguities usually exist when translators do not translate, but interpret the scriptures according to one’s theological believes.  This is falsification of evidence and Christians do not look favorably to it. Christians want Bibles which are translated accurately and without bias, and not what priests, ministers,  scholars or theologians  believes to be true.**

Comment: Translations aren't a primary source, especially when they disagree. A lexicon should be cited to show that the one is correct and the other not rather than anecdotal examples because they can't demonstrate that eis might *not* be used the other way.

Comment: Ruminator: Appreciate you comment. Lexicons should help translators produce accurate translations but do not. Professor of Religious studies, Jason David BeDuhn in his book Truth in Translation, uses similar passages to help clarify the meaning. For example , 2Peter 1:1 and 2 Peter 1:2  have identical grammatical structure , translations in verse 2 maintain the distinction between “God” and  “Jesus, our Lord” while most ignore it in verse 1. Why? Compare also Titus 2:13, Titus 1:4 and 2 Thess.1:12. I recommend you get a copy.

Comment: The professor analyzes John 1:1 the most controversial verse in the Bible, many similar verses in grammar and structure are translated correctly by the same translator, yet when it comes to John 1:1 the grammar is ignored. For example in John 4:19 we must translate “You are a prophet” not “You are the prophet”. In John 8:48 “You are a Samaritan” not “ You are the Samaritan ”, Compare also John 9:24,  12:6, John 4:24 has the same construction a John 1:1c, Acts 28:6  and many others.   
I read fluent Greek, but my grammar is basic, so I avoid it, I use the interlinear and parallel passages .

Comment: I hear what you are saying. Appealing to the original languages often compounds complexity rather than resolving it!

Comment: You say "...Jesus was exalted to a name above all others, by God the Father..." Actually Paul wrote ὁ θεὸς exalted Jesus, not θεοῦ πατρός. You assume the two are interchangeable, despite the obvious distinction Paul makes and the lack of the article when writing θεοῦ πατρός. What the text says is "the" God exalted Jesus to/in the glory of God Father.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**
The translation offered by the OP best suits the entire passage:

> and every tongue confess that [the] Lord Jesus Christ [is] in the glory of God the Father.

Paul begins the statement of glory in verse 6 by speaking of the appearance (glory) of God which Jesus emptied Himself of in order to take on the appearance (sin) of a slave. After His death, the God, ὁ θεὸς, exalted Him in the glory of God [the] Father, θεοῦ πατρός.

Paul has summarized and restated what the Gospel reports Jesus said on His final night:

> <sup>9</sup> Jesus said to him, “Have I been with you so long, and yet you have not known Me, Philip? **He who has seen Me has seen the Father**; so how can you say, ‘Show us the Father’? <sup>10</sup> Do you not believe that I am in the Father, and the Father in Me? The words that I speak to you I do not speak on My own *authority*; but the Father who dwells in Me does the works. <sup>11</sup> Believe Me that I *am* in the Father and the Father in Me, or else believe Me for the sake of the works themselves. (John 14 NKJV)

> <sup>4</sup> I have glorified You on the earth. I have finished the work which You have given Me to do. <sup>5</sup> And now, O Father, **glorify Me together with Yourself, with the glory which I had with You before** the world was. (John 17)

Jesus had the same glory as the Father which He emptied Himself of in order to take on the appearance of a slave. After the humiliation of death on the cross, His original glory was restored. Since Jesus has what He previously had, the glory of the Father, it is best to say He **in the glory of God [the] Father**.

***morphē [not physis] theos* - appearance of God**
From Galatians we see [*morphē*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3444/kjv/tr/0-1/) should be understood as something different from [*physis*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g5449/kjv/tr/0-1/).

> Formerly, when you did not know God, you were enslaved to those that by **nature** are not gods. (4:8 ESV)

Because Paul speaks of the nature in Galatians; he should be taken as saying something different in Philippians. *morphē* means form or external appearance so Paul is saying Jesus had the appearance of God (no article) and He did not consider it robbery to be equal to God (no article).

***morphē doulos* - appearance of a slave**
Paul's meaning of *morphē theos*, appearance of God must be consistent with what he means when he repeats *morphē* in connection with *doulos*:

> who, though he was in the *morphē* of God...taking the *morphē* of a slave
> **Was** *morphē theos* **became** *morphē doulos*

Servant is [*doulos*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g1401/kjv/tr/0-1/) which can be translated as slave. So, according to Paul, Jesus had a *morphē theos*, which He gave up in order to take on a different *morphē*, which was *morphē doulos*.

Using Paul's letter to the Romans, the meaning of *morphē doulos* refers to the **human condition**:

> <sup>16</sup> Do you not know that if you present yourselves to anyone as obedient **slaves**, you are **slaves** of the one whom you obey, either of sin, which leads to death, or of obedience, which leads to righteousness? <sup>17</sup> But thanks be to God, that you who were once **slaves of sin** have become obedient from the heart to the standard of teaching to which you were committed, <sup>18</sup> and, having been set free from sin, have become **slaves of righteousness**. (Romans 6)

All humans are sinners (cf. [Romans 3:23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%203%3A23&version=ESV)) and anyone who sins is a *doulos* to sin. Therefore, when Jesus was in a human body, His **appearance** was like any other human: He **appeared** to be a slave to sin. Of course, there was no sin in Him (cf. [Hebrews 4:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%204%3A15&version=ESV)).

In Romans, Paul personifies sin: the sinner is a slave to "Master" Sin. Jesus, on the other hand, has the **appearance** of a *doulos*. He is not a sinner and sin is not His master. Now, if one takes Paul as only narrowly focused on the sin nature of man, Philippians would mean:

> He was the appearance of God, in other words He was without sin...and He took on the appearance of a slave, in other words, He looked like every sinner whose Master is Sin

***morphē theos* = the glory of the Father**
A limited understanding of *morphē theos* as speaking only of God's sinlessness means Jesus, like God, was without sin. In this narrow sense translations like the NIV which treat *morphē theos* as the **nature** of God, are not wrong. However, that understanding does not make sense when seen in how Paul introduces the subject of *morphē doulos*:

> but emptied himself, taking the form of a servant

Since He was already without sin, He could not empty Himself from sin. So then, what was the appearance He gave up in order to take on the appearance of a slave?

> <sup>4</sup> I have glorified You on the earth. I have finished the work which You have given Me to do. <sup>5</sup> And now, O Father, glorify Me together with Yourself, with the glory which I had with You before the world was. (John 17)

The appearance Paul is speaking of is glory which He had with the Father.

> who, having the appearance of God [the glory of the Father] did not consider it robbery to be equal with God [the Father] so He emptied Himself [of this glory] and took on the appearance of a slave, coming in the likeness of men

Then Paul completes the passage by indicating what Jesus emptied Himself of was returned, *to the glory of God the Father*. Here Paul not only omits the article, He makes a further distinction between the glory of God and glory of the Father:

> For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God (Romans 3:23)

God here is written with the article, τοῦ Θεοῦ.

**Conclusion**
In Romans, Paul states all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God; in Philippians Paul states Jesus humiliation ends with glory of God Father. The two are not in contradiction because Jesus only took on the **appearance** of a slave (sinner). As such He did not fall short of the glory of God.

However, in order to take on the appearance of a sinner He had to empty Himself of His appearance as God. That is, He gave up the glory He had with the Father from the before the world was. In His appearance as a slave, He did not fall short of the glory of God (with the article); He was simply without the glory of God Father since He had emptied Himself of that appearance.

Paul's letter to the Philippians is an explicit statement the request Jesus made, *glorify Me together with Yourself, with the glory which I had with You before the world was* was answered.

Answer (score -2):

εἰς is rather "to", "towards", "to the effect" than "in", yet the latter can also translate it in certain instances. In this sense, in Latin εἰς would be better translated by "ad", like in expression "ad majorem dei gloriam" ("to/towards the greater glory of God") which in Greek would be εἰς τὴν μεγίστην δόξαν θεοῦ. For instance, in James 1:19: ταχὺς εἰς τὸ ἀκοῦσαι, βραδὺς εἰς τὸ λαλῆσαι, βραδὺς εἰς ὀργήν ([man should be] "quick to listen (towards listening), slow to talk (towards talking), slow to wrath (towards being wrathful"), but the "in" can also do, "be slow in talking", when "in" entails the notion of "in relation with".

In Philiphians 2:11 the prevailing understanding you bring is the soundest, for the passage implies conditionality: if you want to glorify the Father as God, then you cannot do this but by acknowledging and confessing the Lordship and Godhead of Jesus. Thus, Arians or Jehovah Witnessians, lacking this necessary precondition in their common theologies, cannot glorify God properly in principle, according to the logic of this Pauline passage. The same is asserted by John, that whoever does not acknowledge the Son, that is to say, the Godhead of the Son, and does not pay Him the equal honor as to the Father (John 5:23),  such a heretical man would have neither the Father, that is to say, the Father as God (1 John 2:23).

Comment: @Downvoter Dear, my, precious, downvote at pleasure, I care not a tiny bit for points, I am no idiot, but please substantiate and write the reasons, for this is interesting and the site is developed for the reason of interesting discussions. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, a "forum" is for discussion. Here what is sought are authoritative answers from primary sources. I was not the original down voter but I did add my down vote because you cite no primary sources and get up on your Trinitarian soapbox .

Comment: @Ruminator Primary source is Gospel, which I have cited. The Godhead and Lordship of Jesus is clearly asserted here, unless one blinds his/her eye, as it is asserted in many other passages, couple of which I have quoted here as well. Your based-on-nothing-but-emotion harangue against Trinity proves that you have had some personal distress against a priest or somebody in your life-experience, so is a sheer psychology, having nothing to do with theology and this site. But if you follow sincerely logic and sound sense, it is impossible not to come to glorification of Trinity, which I wish you.

Comment: As a primary source for the Greek usage of words is much better served by an appropriate lexicon rather than anecdotal evidence when available. LSJ is available online. As to "confessing the Lordship and Godhead of Jesus", "lordship" is contextual but since it is granted by God because of obedience and for God's glory I should say it is anti-contextual. You come to the text with an axe to grind. Can't you see that? Can you not admit to it?

Comment: @Ruminator I can give evidences from dictionaries and TLG as well, for I am a classicist and know ancient Greek quite well. In my scholarly articles I do properly all quotations. Here I can be less strict and say things without rigid adherence to my habitual asceticism. As to your theological point: yes, you are right, that lordship to humanity of Jesus was given due to His obedience, but before even becoming human, He as God's Logos and Son, with neither material body nor created intelligent soul, was Lord and God, equal (ἴσα) to God Father, without any obedience, but naturally (Phil. 2:6-7).

Comment: Would it be wrong to assume that the sense of the Latin 'in' here is that of, e.g. the part of the Creed: Confiteor unum baptisma in remissionem peccatorum (I confess one baptism for/unto the remission of sins)?

Comment: Yes, quite possible, for εἰς can mean "to the purpose of", and the English "in" can also indicate the purpose, like in expression "teacher said tough words  i n  admonition of a student", and so in Latin, I guess, more rarely the "in" can have this meaning like in "venire in auxiliam" (to come for/with a purpose of a help). Here it is said that for the purpose of glorifying in a due way the Father, one has to acclaim Jesus' Lordship/Godhead as the necessary precondition, for it is ontologically impossible to glorify God as Father, unless through acclaiming God-ness of His Son.

Comment: P.S. Vulgate assumes that "est" should be put before "εἰς δόξαν", and thus, it will be another meaning: "Jesus is in glory of the Father", but then "in" means place, not purpose, which is also possible, for humanity of Jesus participates in Father's glory derivatively; yet, the context of the Phil. 2 (verses 6-7) rather suggests a loftier explanation, for it says Jesus is in the equal status with Father before Incarnation, so that the divine appellation "Lord" applies not only to the Father, but to Jesus too, thus, putting ἐστὶ is rather implied between Κύριος and Ἰησοῦς, i.e. "Jesus is Lord".